# How to make Angular ngRepeat filter on the view value?

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'm iterating through a data array with ngRepeat making table rows. This iteration is filtered with a multiple-column filter of my making. The columns of the table are created by a nested ngRepeat that iterates through a columns array. The value of each cell could potentially be passed to a 'lookup' filter to transform the cell's data value into a 'finished' value. (Like transforming 'Y' into 'Yes' and 'N' into 'No'. The transformations are not limited to 'Yes' or 'No' type things. There are a few various ones.)

It looks like something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in data | multiColumnFilter : filters">
  <td ng-repeat="column in columns | orderBy : 'order'">
    <span ng-if="column.lookup">{{row[column.alias] | lookup : column.lookup}}</span>
    <span ng-if="!column.lookup">{{row[column.alias]}}</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My problem is this:

I want the user to be able to filter the table's contents on the visible text in the table cell, like 'Yes' or 'No'. But what's stored in the data array is 'Y' or 'N'.

I'm trying to avoid pre-transforming my array because I also want to preserve the raw data values for use in other parts of the application.

I suspect that I will need to keep a redundant set of data that represents the transformed values. Given the overhead of that (it's a large data array) I'd rather find a way to filder on the view value, rather than the data value.

Comment: can simply add arguments to your filter using `:` in markup to match argument position in function

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to help if you could post a plunker or jsfiddle, but I'll give it a shot.

Let's say the user wants to view only the "Yes" entries. You then need to identify the raw data value ("Y") that corresponds to the view value "Yes", and filter by that. So essentially you need something like this:

```
function filterBy(column, viewValue) {
    var rawValue = viewValue;
    if (column.lookup)  {
        data.some(function(row) { 
            if (column.lookup(row[column])==viewValue) {
                rawValue = row[column];
                return true;
            }
            else return false; 
        });
    }
    return data.filter(function(row) { return row[column]==rawValue; });
}
```

Note: the use of **some()** means that the loop will stop as soon the first match is found.